# How to save a query or macro in MS Access using pyodbc?

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

There’re a lot of tips online on how to use pyodbc to run a query in MS Access, and how to call queries already saved in MS Access, but is there a way to **store a query/macro in MS Access**, using pyodbc, win32com or other ?

It must then be possible to execute the saved request from MS Access.

(My goal is for the user to be able to execute the requests himself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a saved SELECT query via Access ODBC as follows:

```py
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
query_name = "query1"
# emulate DROP VIEW IF EXISTS
view_names = [x.table_name for x in crsr.tables(tableType="VIEW").fetchall()]
if query_name in view_names:
    crsr.execute(f"DROP TABLE {query_name}")  # yes, DROP TABLE
crsr.execute(f"""
CREATE VIEW {query_name} AS 
SELECT * FROM Donor WHERE DonorID = 1 
"""
)
cnxn.commit()
```

You can perform a lot more low-level manipulation of the Access database via `win32com` and `DAO.DBEngine.120`, but user macros (as opposed to data macros) are a bit of a strange creature in Access and AFAIK you cannot do much with those via DAO.

Comment: Okay, the "create view" statement create a new query. Simple ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

To add, remember <kbd>[**ms-access**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ms-access/info)</kbd> is a [*multifaceted thing*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33216/ms-access-or-mdb-or-access-database-engine-or-ms-jet-ace). Over the years the underlying database (JET/ACE engine) and GUI application has been conflated as "Access database". But these are two different components.

- Anything involving the GUI application (MSACCESS.exe) such as [data macros](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-data-macro-b1b94bca-4f17-47ad-a66d-f296ef834200#), general macros, modules, forms, and reports cannot be processed in ODBC connections which runs in the non-visual background of programming languages. Additionally, MS Access, the Office application, must be installed to adjust GUI objects.

  You can still create/delete tables and queries with Access' [TableDefs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/tabledef-object-dao) and [QueryDefs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/querydef-object-dao), both part of its object library using code. Please note: interacting with Access' [object library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/access/object-model) is not limited to VBA but is available to any COM-connected language including Python with `win32com` module; C# and VB.Net with `InteropServices`; PHP with `COM` library; Perl with `Win32::OLE` module; R with `RDCOMClient` package, and still others. Such COM programming requires MSACCESS.exe, the software, installed.
- Anything involving the database (JET/ACE engine) which are Windows .dll files such as tables and queries can be processed in ODBC or OLEDB connections. Additionally, MS Access, the Office application, does NOT need to be installed to run ODBC connections on `.mdb` or `.accdb` files. The only requirement is having a Windows environment and ODBC driver.

  Therefore, as @GordonThompson [shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64156348/1422451), DDL (`CREATE TABLE`, `CREATE VIEW`, `CREATE PROCEDURE`, `CREATE INDEX`, `DROP TABLE`) and DML (`SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`) calls can work in ODBC connections to manipulate database but not GUI objects.

Comment: For the record, `CREATE PROCEDURE` works with ACE/.accdb, too. Example [here](https://pastebin.com/nE3X8Ab1).

Comment: @GordThompson, hmmmm...`CREATE PROCEDURE` doesn't work for me in MS Access 2016 .accdb / 64-bit in Python `pyodbc` using an ODBC driver with any action SQL query. But `CREATE VIEW` does. Interestingly, `PROCEDURE` does work with `adodbapi` using OLEDB provider and `VIEW` does not work in `adodbapi`. What is the connection string you use in example?

Comment: My test was with Access 2013 ODBC. I've also gotten into the habit of tacking `;ExtendedAnsiSQL=1` onto the end of my connection strings, so that may have something to do with it.

Comment: @GordThompson, that extended parameter was the missing piece. Good to learn and know!